Hydrohalogenation: Why don't carbocations attack alkenes?
Why don't carbocations attack alkenes in their hydrohalogenation? For example, in the addition of $\ce{HBr}$ to propylene, why is the carbocation intermediate unable to attack another propylene molecule, forming a larger carbocation?
It seems like this would be favorable: a $\ce{C-C}$ π-bond is being replaced with a $\ce{C-C}$ σ-bond, and a secondary carbocation would be turned into a tertiary one after rearrangement.
Is it steric hinderance that is preventing this, even with a small terminal alkene?

They do, but HBr doesn't look like a good catalyst for cationic di/oligo/polymerisation. Br- is a pretty strong nucleophile.
